# How to endlessly scroll an image?

Tags: android

I have listview.  When it's empty, I would like it to have the appearance of endlessly scrolling lined paper when there are no items in the list.

[image]

I could use an endless adapter and empty views but that seems like overkill.

Is there a way to endlessly scroll an image?  If there is, my plan is to use this method in a view set via `setEmptyView()`.

I can't show you what I've tried, since I can't figure out what to try ;)

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless
This sounds like what you're looking for...

Comment: @IncrediApp Thank you. I know how to use an endless adapter, but I'm hoping for some simple way to implement this.  An XML only solution would be perfect but I'm not hopeful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `View` subclass, which handles `onTouchEvent` for scrolling (use `View.post` with some `Interpolator` for swipe effect or anything else that makes it less code to write) and `onDraw` to draw the lines.

Comment: Thank you.  This is a good answer but I'm hoping there is some easy way.  If I create a custom view, I may as well just implement an endless adapter.

Comment: Well, looks like there isn't a simple way so I did just as you said.  Thanks.